# Office js conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins

I am currently trying to implement conditional formatting in Excel using Office JS API 1.6 .I have written the following code to implement text comparison formatting.

```
function textComparisonFormatting() {
        // Run a batch operation against the Excel object model
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {

            // Create a proxy object for the active worksheet
            var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

            //Queue a command to write the sample data to the specified range
            //in the worksheet and bold the header row
            var range = sheet.getRange("A2:E8");

            var conditionalFormat = range.conditionalFormats.add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.textComparison);

            conditionalFormat.textComparison.load(["rule","format/*","format/fill"]);

            //Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion
            return ctx.sync(conditionalFormat).then(function(conditionalFormat){

                conditionalFormat.textComparison.rule.text = "Qtr";
                conditionalFormat.textComparison.rule.operator = "BeginsWith";
                conditionalFormat.textComparisonformat.fill.color = "red";
            });
        })
        .then(function () {
            app.showNotification("Success");
            console.log("Success!");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // Always be sure to catch any accumulated errors that bubble up from the Excel.run execution
            app.showNotification("Error: " + error);
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
    }
```

The code is throwing InvalidObjectPath error while i am trying to set the color. If i try to set the colors inside Excel.Run(), then it won't work as i am unable to access the object properties. Is there any way by which I can resolve these issues?

Answer (score 2):

Some changes you should make to your code:

1. You don't need to load anything and sync, because you are writing to the properties, not reading them.
2. There is no `ConditionalFormatType.textComparison`. You need `ConditionalFormatType.containsText`.
3. Operators are camel-cased: `beginsWith`, not `BeginsWith`.
4. There should be a "." between `textComparison` and `format`.

This snippet works:

```
function applyTextFormat() {
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        var range = sheet.getRange("A2:E8");
        var conditionalFormat = range.conditionalFormats
            .add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.containsText);
        conditionalFormat.textComparison.format.fill.color = "red";
        conditionalFormat.textComparison.rule = { operator: Excel.ConditionalTextOperator.beginsWith, text: "Qtr" };

        return context.sync();
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**: As the OP requested:
The documentation is not yet published on dev.office.com. You need to go to a special branch of the office-js-docs repo on GitHub. Open this page and see all the files of the form conditional*.md: 
[ExcelJs_OpenSpec/reference/excel](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_OpenSpec/reference/excel)

Comment: Can you please share the latest documentation link form where i can get all the possible properties and relationships for Excel.ConditonalFormatType ?